# Why this extra space that I'm creating is pushing the Element instead of creating some scrollable extra space?

Tags: javascript, android, css, vue.js, mobile

I'm in a Vuejs big project, and I was assigned a kinda simple task => in Mobile version the  keyboard overlaps an input and the user can't see what he's writing. So what I did was: add a @focus="handleFocus" event on an input which triggers a class .add on the Layout div and .remove it in @blur. Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div
    ref="divMain"
    class="h-screen bg-white sm:flex sm:flex-wrap sm:justify-center sm:text-center mainLayout"
  >
    <PageHeader
      :noRedirect="step > 0"
      :progress="progress"
      class="h-28"
      @back="back()"
    >
      <h2
        class="h-14 flex items-center text-xl text-primary font-semibold sm:hidden"
      >
        {{ t('createAccount') }}
      </h2>
      <Logo class="w-20 h-12 hidden sm:inline-block" />
    </PageHeader>

    <component
      :is="forms[step].name"
      class="max-w-lg mx-auto p-4"
      @submit="forms[step].handler($event)"
      @inFocus="layoutChange"
      @inBlur="removelChange"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, computed, onMounted } from 'vue'



export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CreateAccount',
  components: {
    PageHeader,
    Logo,
    FullNameForm,
    ContactInformationForm,
    PhoneVerificationForm,
    LocationForm,
    BirthdayForm,
    ProfilePhotoForm,
    GenderForm,
    RatingForm,
    ClaimProfileForm,
    CountryForm,
    EmailVerificationForm
  },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    
   
    const divMain = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
    const layoutChange = () => {
      if (divMain.value) {
        divMain.value.classList.add('keyboard')
      }
    }

    const removelChange = () => {
      if (divMain.value) {
        divMain.value.classList.remove('keyboard')
      }
    }

    return {
      t,
      step,
      forms,
      back,
      next,
      progress,
      getAccountData,
      layoutChange,
      removelChange,
      divMain
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style>
.mainLayout.keyboard {
  height: calc(100% + 500px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Ignore the comoponents:{} => I deleted all the things in setup() not related to the question.

This is how you see the screen initially:
[image]
And this is how you see it after the class is active:
[image]

I have no experience in mobile Development so I don't know if when the keyboards arrives the class will add extra space for it. I'm quite lost, some help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mobile view]

See this button? It changes your browser to mobile view. What you see with that enabled is pretty much exactly what actual mobile users will see